# Dynamic Change Tracking Query error?

Tags: sql-server

We are trying to run the below Query.

```
DECLARE @CounterNumber INT = 1
WHILE @CounterNumber <= 3
BEGIN 
    Declare @name varchar(255)
    Set @name = (Select Name from TableList where id = @CounterNumber)
    SELECT CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION() as CurrentChangeTrackingVersion
    SELECT SYS_CHANGE_VERSION FROM [dbo].[table_store_ChangeTracking_version] WHERE TableName = @name
    
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

    DECLARE @currentVersion bigint  
    Set @currentVersion = (SELECT TOP 1 SYS_CHANGE_VERSION  FROM table_store_ChangeTracking_version WHERE TableName=@name)

    DECLARE @newVersion bigint = CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION()

    SET @sql = 'SELECT
        Ct.sys_change_Operation,
        CT.sys_change_version,
        CT.id as ct_id,
        @name.* 
        FROM @name
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN CHANGETABLE(CHANGES dbo.@name, @currentVersion) CT ON @name.Id = CT.Id'

    SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@name', quotename(@name))
    
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
    set @CounterNumber = @CounterNumber + 1
END;
```

But we are getting error stating:

Must declare the scalar variable "@currentVersion".

Can anyone help me understand what is wrong our here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass parameter to your dynamic query correctly:
`EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@currentVersion bigint', @currentVersion = @currentVersion`